# Optimizing jar file size (images) when developing java client supporting multiple languages

Tags: java, image, optimization, internationalization

I am developing the Java client which should support several languages. For translation of the text I use Java ResourceBoundle and it works okay.

Now the problem is with images. The client should load around 50 images which are specific cards for a board game. Each image has a title. So if I have N languages I should prepare 50*N images and put then into the jar file.

Each language support would add around 1 Mb to the size of jar file.

Do you think I should

1. Generate jar which support all the languages?
2. Generate many jars which would support English and a local language?
3. Have one set of image without titles and attach title to the image using Java JLabel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise another option altogether.

Have a set of images without text, and use AWT's [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) to add the text in the necessary language (as opposed to doing so with a JLabel).

```
Graphics2D g = imageBase.createGraphics();
// color, font, etc settings
g.drawString("title", 0, 0);
g.dispose();
```

You can modify the parameters of `g.drawString` as necessary to draw the correct title at the correct coordinates. If you wish to center the title, you can find a nice tutorial [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI-appearance/fonts/18font.html).

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov It will also look much better. Text in graphics doesn't work well. Drawing text directly via fonts works far better.

Comment: @EJP where do I get createGraphics? I use BufferedImage, ImageIcon, Image classes to keep the images.